# NullPointerException while setting firstname in vcard in smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

Getting NullPointerException while setting firstname in vcard
when i'm setting nickname its working fine but when setting firstname getting null pointer exception

i'm using this code

```
VCard vCard = null;
VCardManager vCardManager = VCardManager.getInstanceFor(conn);
try {
    vCard = vCardManager.loadVCard();
    try {
        vCard.setNickName(imageurl);
        vCard.setFirstName("Scheller");
        vCard.save(conn);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

on setFirstName its crashing with this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException exception. Cannot evaluate org.jivesoftware.smackx.vcardtemp.packet.VCard.toString()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with smack, but in this line `vCard.setFirstName` , this looks highly irregular.

Comment: Always show the full stacktrace when asking about the cause of an exception!

Answer (score 1):

1.instead of:

```
VCard vCard = null;
```

try creating a new object of VCard :

```
VCard vCard = new VCard();
```

2.also instead of these 2 lines :

```
VCardManager vCardManager = VCardManager.getInstanceFor(conn);
vCard = vCardManager.loadVCard();
```

do it like this :

```
vCard.load(conn);
```

see if it helps with your problem